# Graph - Hide zero or non value values

Tags: excel, graph, show-hide

I want them to be hidden in the graph zero (or non value) values like Here:

[image]

That I get manually after filter setup. But is it possible to do it automatically?

Because when I reset my filter, it shows also others categories with zero values, like here:

[image]

In my table I have to have zero value so I don't want to delete them. Is other way (graph setup) to get a goal?

Answer (score 0):

I got it myself:) (That's the best feeling :D )

Just right click on graph Main Axis-> Filter -> Set up value..

Nevertheless thank you:)